# How to set Countdown timer stop at 00:00:00 OR when =0 auto click button

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer

When my timer goes to 00:00:00 the next second will keep Counting down like 23:59:59.
How do I stop the timer at 00:00:00 OR when timer = 00:00:00 auto click button

button

```
<input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result' id='submitpaper'>
```

display

```
<div id=response class=timer style=font-size:30px></div>
```

This is the First.php

```
$duration=$row["duration"];


$_SESSION["duration"]=$duration;
$_SESSION["start_time"]=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$end_time=$end_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'.$_SESSION["duration"].'minutes',strtotime($_SESSION["start_time"])));

$_SESSION["end_time"]=$end_time;
?>
```

Here is my response.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$from_time1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1=$_SESSION["end_time"];
$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);

$differenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;
echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceinseconds);

?>
```

The JavaScript is on where the time display page.

```
    var x = setInterval(test,1000); 
function test()
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","response.php",false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit response php to

```
<?php
session_start();

$from_time1=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time1=$_SESSION["end_time"];
$timefirst=strtotime($from_time1);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time1);
$differenceinseconds=$timesecond-$timefirst;
//if countdown smaller than 0, countdown should be 0
if($differenceinseconds<0)$differenceinseconds=0;

echo gmdate("H:i:s",$differenceinseconds);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you know how to submit form or autoclick button when $differenceinseconds = 0
Like
`if($differenceinseconds<0){
$differenceinseconds =0;
button click/ submit form
}`